# Ubuntu Server Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 hangs on first reboot

Tags: 16.04, server, 18.04, upgrade

Just upgraded an instance of Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.04 and the install hangs at boot, last line emitted to the terminal is Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04!

Instance is a VM on an R2008 HyperV.

I suspect this hang is a result of the original appliance configured as a 32bit system and 18.04 only supporting 64bit, just a hunch.

Most recent snapshot is from 10/2017 (so much for backup policies).

I wouldn't be shocked if recovering this instance isn't possible, Has anyone gone through this?
Is it possible to extract the install and run it from another appliance or at the very least recover some of the application data into another proper 18.04 instance?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question but did you try a second reboot or a cold boot later?

Comment: Yea tried that, it just hangs at the same spot. server accepts the poweroff signal but never completes the shutdown cycle, have to force with HyperV

Comment: Is it possible it's not really hung though? and it's just doing some really long running background task? I'm totally doubtful of this but is it a possibility?

Comment: Change `grub` and remove `quiet splash` and read system messages.

Comment: Didn't even have a chance to, imported the VHD's into another VM(64bit) fired right up.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some deeper research there seems to be an issue with the recent Linux kernel version 4.15 and HyperV 2008R2. Rolling back to an older kernel fixed this.
This bug report tipped me off -https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1814069

In my case, I had to boot the VM on a Linux instance with Virtual Box, and purge the most recent kernel through apt. I didn't have to install anything as there were already previous kernels still installed.  I updated grub and transferred my updated image back to my HyperV instance. Now works as expected.